# Using Stored Procedure into Select (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to access the result of a stored procedure within a select statement, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sp_sample]
```

in SQL_Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Barry is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515955/using-stored-procedure-into-select-t-sql/2515996#2515996) you need to create a temp table and insert into it first, then join that table in your select.

However, there are numerous ways for sharing data between stored procedures, see this excellent article: [How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

One method that may work for you is to "share" a temp table.  The #temp table is created in the Parent procedure and can be used by the Child: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#temptables

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible.  You would have to create a temporary table to store the results.

```
Create Table #tmp
(
...
)
Insert into #tmp
Exec dbo.StoredProcedure
```

The table structure must match the output of the Stored Procedure.

Comment: in fact, my select statement is into a view ... any idea

I use a SP because I need a temporary table.