# Call SP from another SP with result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, resultset

I have a stored procedure in which I have called another stored procedure [Let say I have parent stored procedure which is calling child SP]. Child stored procedure have a result set which have almost 10,000 records. How can I get it in the parent stored procedure?

```
Parent SP 
(
 Student INT
 Teacher INT
 Name Varchar
)

Child SP [Get Student specific activities] Student

-- Result Set of Child SP needed Here

-- End of Parent SP
```

Comment: see this previous similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515955/using-stored-procedure-into-select-t-sql/2516129#2516129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One was is to use `INSERT... EXECUTE...` Within the parent stored procedure, have something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (StudentId int null, <Other columns as required>)

INSERT #Temp
 EXECUTE ChildSP
```

The (single!) data set returned by the child SP must match the table structure of #Temp.

Comment: Not working for me. Says incorrect syntax near execute keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You would store the results of your child stored procedure into a temp table and access those records in the parent stored procedure by selecting from the temp table.